# How to run/configure Jmeter for HTTP PUT/POST method. How to set Dynamic data in jmeter payload to avoid Database duplicate constraint error

Tags: rest, jmeter, microservices

I am new to JMeter. I need to do performance testing for a microservice. I have "PUT" methods. I need to run JMeter with 25 threads and maximum of 2000 ramp-up time. I am using the payload values from csv files.

**Problem**: The script process goes as follow:

1. 1st thread runs and inserts the companyID XX details which are non-duplicate 
   values at DB.
2. 2nd thread runs and tries to insert another companyID details, but for some 
   reason it tries to insert the same details inserted by the 1st thread and 
   that gives an error.

**Question**: How Can I make Payload data dynamic so that each thread get unique 
   data.

If my approach is wrong, then please suggest me how can I make each thread chose unique values from the CSV file. If I have inserted 25 unique records in csv file, then also it means, 1 thread is performing on the application at one time with one set of data, that's not a performance testing.

Please suggest, How can I do it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you attached your CSV Data Set configuration? and test plan if possible

Comment: In csv file, the values are separated by tab and I am fetching those values using $ in my jmeter configuration. Its working for 1 thread, But if I make threads to 25 to check its performance, I couldn't do that as 1st thread inserted the data and DB won't take duplicate values.

Comment: How are you reading the data from the csv file?

Answer (score 0):

In "CSV Data Set Config" there are many optional configurations you can adjust. In your case, I think you should set the "Sharing mode" to "All Threads", also set the "Recycle on EOF" to "False".

Other thing to try is to use different CSV files for each thread.

[This is a very helpful step by step tutorial to check](http://blogs.quovantis.com/how-to-do-parameterization-in-jmeter-using-csv/)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to have unique values in the csv file.

Then in csv configuration set "recycle on eof" as False and "stop thread on EOF" as true, sharing mode as "all threads"
This will have unique value for each thread and threads will stop if there is no new value.

Hope this helps.